# Describe this type of rotor from a three phase induction motor?

Tags: motor, ac, three-phase, induction-motor, rotor

[image]After CNC machining the rotor, to expose the outer surface of the silicon iron, this proves to be exactly the same as the inner surface was (the one facing the core).Just plain electric iron rings without skews/copper/aluminium bars. There are just six iron rivets holding them all together.
There was a thin sheet of aluminium (about 0.25mm thick) covering the rotor's electric steel from the inside too. What type of rotor is this? Where can i look it up?

Comment: The slot looks to be for a Hall Sensor for BLDC motors

Comment: Not at all. It was empty and i guess it's there for alignment.

Comment: What does the stator look like? Is there a nameplate on the housing? Are you sure it is an induction motor? Can you post pictures showing the inside and the other end?

Comment: It's a three phase induction motor with external rotor. This is established beyond doubt. I have measured the copper turns (it's 260) on 0.3mm thick wire, double loops in every core slot, 24 slot, 8 poles, 1 to 4 slot pattern, 6 end wires combined in three terminals, delta configuration.

Comment: Does it use variable speed control and bi-directional?  ( external rotor?) what does the stator look like?

Comment: Yes it does. It's a DENON motor used in transcription turntables.

Comment: And external equals outer. The stator is ordinary silicon steel with 24 slots and copper wiring.

Comment: could it be a direct  VFD since it is low RPM

Comment: Is it a Hysteresis motor? They use the hysteresis of the magnetic material so that they run synchronously once they get close to speed.

Comment: I too think that this is from a hysteresis motor, but one that has an EXTERNAL rotor, so likely on a fan or turntable. Hysteresis motors are very inefficient, but also constant torque, very quiet and exhibit very low vibration. So they are used when there are acoustic issues or on inertia loads where vibration is intolerable.

Comment: Hmmm...by reading some it seems that this could be the type of this motor. Can this type of motor be combined with 3 phase operation?